# What to troubleshoot MEF C#

Tags: c#, plugins, mef

The following demo application on MEF technology does not work.
Can't build the simplest extensible application. I started with the simplest, a console application that will simply display text on the screen according to the specified parameters. And even here he did not go to me. Where to dig?

IDemoInterface.cs

```
public interface IDemoInretface
{
    void Run(int sleep, int count);
}
```

MEFDataDemo
Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.IO;

namespace MEFDataDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.Run();
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            DoImport();
            int count = 1;
            foreach (var item in Plugin)
            {
                item.Value.Run(count * 1000, count * 10);*** This is Error
                count++;
            }
        }

        [ImportMany(typeof(IDemoInretface))]
        public IEnumerable<Lazy<IDemoInretface>> Plugin { get; set; }

        public void DoImport()
        {
            var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Plugins");
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(path));
            var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            container.ComposeParts(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Plugin1 Class1.cs

```
    using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Threading;

namespace Plugin1
{
    [Export(typeof(IDemoInretface))]
    internal class Class1 : IDemoInretface
    {
        public void Run(int sleep, int count)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This plugin1 print {0}/{1} in {2}ms", i, count, sleep);
                Thread.Sleep(sleep);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
The program compiles, but either does not read plugins, or reads but does not run the (RUN) method

Comment: Did you look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/)?

Comment: I looked, did it by analogy, but does not work.